# perform a random for loop and save the random values each time

Tags: c++

I would like to pick a random part of a set (for e.g a normal for loop which excludes some random values) and store the excluded values each time.

for this short example in a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++){

//test1

do smthing with the i's between 0-19 except (3 and 14)

//test2

do smthing with the i's between 0-19 except (0 and 1)

//test3

do smthing with the i's between 0-19 except (19 and 5)
...

//testn

do smthing with the i's between 0-19 except (...)

}
```

`

I would like the "except part" to differ at each step, to store it in a vector and to be able to define the number of points that are avoid.

Is there an easiest way to achieve this in C++.

I found this function on the web, but it is limited to one point only:

```
// Generate a random number between nLow and nHigh (inclusive)
unsigned int GetRandomNumber(int nLow, int nHigh)
{
return (rand() % (nHigh - nLow + 1)) + nLow;
}
```

In pratice the loop have 5844 steps and 854 are excluded. The following code was proposed to me:

```
for(int test = 0; test < 5844; test++)
int exclude[854];
exclude[0] = rand()%5844;
exclude[1] = rand()%5844;
.
.
.
exclude[854] = rand()%5844; //(but too long even with a loop)
for(int i = 0; i < 5844; i++) {
if(i == exclude[0] || i == exclude[1] || ...||i == exclude[854]) continue;
// do work...
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the order of iteration important (i.e., is it a problem if the loop executes for `i = 10` before it executes `i = 1`)?

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue here is that the "except part" will have more than only 2 values? What is the problem with the proposed solution?

Comment: With the proposed solution, i wonder if the value in exclude will always be differents from each other or not ? I should check `rand()`  function I guess.  And it requires a additional loop to fill exclude. I'm looking at a straightforward solution.

Comment: In response to your comment left on my answer: So, what does your actual  loop look like? `for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) ...`? Are you just looping from  0 to some number *n*, or are you iterating over a vector or set of values? Could you perhaps update the example in your question to be closer to what you have actually written in your application?

Comment: Done, the example has been updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, multiple excluded numbers could potentially have the same value. You could use some of C++11's new `random` features to ensure all of the numbers are different. Here is a possible solution, using `std::shuffle`; this could likely be optimized, but there is no reason to do so unless the runtime is too long for your needs:

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <algorithm> // std::shuffle
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <numeric>   // std::iota
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine rng{std::random_device{}()};

int main()
{
    // Our initial set [0-5843]
    std::vector<int> vec(5844);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);

    // Take a random subset of 854 elements
    const int exclude{854};
    std::shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rng);
    std::vector<int> excluded(vec.end()-exclude, vec.end());
    vec.erase(vec.end()-exclude, vec.end());

    std::cout << "Do work for " << vec.size() << " elements.\n";
    for (int i : vec) {
        // Do work...
    }

    std::cout << "Excluded " << excluded.size() << " elements.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this changes the order of iteration. For example, when doing work, `i = 100` may be executed before `i = 10`.

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/UNV41074)

Comment: Thanks, but in pratice the size is not limited to two integers. I would like to have exclude[854].

Comment: @rdk77: Oh, that changes everything.  Edit your question then, because that's very relevant.  (Especially with how do you exclude 854 numbers from the range of 1-20?)

Comment: @MooingDuck You are funny.

Comment: @rdk77 I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

We know how many valid numbers there are, so first pick a number in that range:

```
static std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(nLow, nHigh-ignored.size());
unsigned value = dis(gen);
```

Then, for each invalid number less than or equal to the one we picked, we have to increase the value by one.  Luckily, this is a trivial operation.  (Note: the `ignored` values have to be sorted in increasing order)

```
auto it = std::upper_bound(ignored.begin(), ignored.end(), value);
value += it-ignored.begin();
```

Finally, *that* operation may have advanced us past a couple more disallowed numbers, so we'll advance past those until we're good.  This might advance us past others, so this is the tricky part logically, even if the code is simple.  The `it!=ignored.end()` is a sanity check, that should be impossible.

```
while(it != ignored.end() && *it<= value) {
    ++it;
    ++value;
}
```

That's it!  You can see it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28b40f978a90216c